# What are good some good analysis texts on p-expansions for real numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, p-adic-number-theory

I'm self-studying real analysis, And I want some good references to study the p-expansions of real numbers.

Comment: I know next to nothing about the subject, but it seems to fall, rather, under analytic number theory.  Take a look at the bibliography by J.-P. Serre, especially these two:

Abelian ℓ-Adic Representations and Elliptic Curves (1968), CRC Press, reissue. Addison-Wesley. 1989.[9]

Cours d'arithmétique (1970), PUF, as A Course in Arithmetic (1973), Springer-Verlag

Comment: See [$p$-**Adic Numbers. An Introduction**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/3540629114) by Fernando Gouvea. I was looking at books on this topic a few years ago, and from what I can recall, I believe his book would work well for your situation.

Comment: There's a lot of study on $b$-ary expansions (and much more), but this is an area of active research. You'll have to refine your question.

Answer (score 1):

Real numbers do not *have* $p$-adic expansions. If you’re asking for $p$-adic expansions of rational numbers, that’s fine, but the real number $\pi$, for instance, is meaningless in any $p$-adic context.

Even the innocuous number $e$, for instance, can not be given any sensible definition $p$-adically. The series for $\exp(x)$ is not convergent at $1$, so you may ask, “Well, why not the value such that $\log(e)=1$, please?” But that’s no good. The series $\log(1+x)=x-x^2/2+x^3-3-\cdots$ has a rather large domain of convergence, but you easily see that setting it equal to $1$ gives you infinitely many roots, and among these, no single one can be discerned as preferable to all the others.

So my recommendatrion to you is to follow the advice of commenter @DaveL.Renfro and look into the wonderful book by Gouvêa.